# Report Viewer #Error on table

Tags: c#, reportviewer

[image]

Hello.

Does anyone know how to find why there is a #error instead of data on my report? The report was working just fine until today, i haven't changed anything on the code and now i get this #error thing. How can i debug it and see where is the cause of it? I have debugged my code and i got no exception in it. The code im using to load the report is:

```
public static bool LoadSurveillanceDataInReport(ref ReportViewer rpt, DateTime dStart, DateTime dEnd, double kilometersDroven)
        {
            try
            {
                reportPath = @"C:\MSRDS4\bin\Reports\SurveillanceReport.rdlc";
                pdfName = "Surveillance_Report_" + dStart.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_').Replace('-', '_');

                bool hasDetections = false;
                bool hasTaken = false;

                //Get Surveillance data
                IList<ClsSurveillanceTasks> surveillanceTasks = GetTaskData(dStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dEnd.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                if (surveillanceTasks == null)
                    return false;
                else if (surveillanceTasks.Count > 0)
                    hasTaken = true;


                IList<ClsSurveillanceDetections> surveillanceDetection = GetDetectionData(dStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dEnd.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                if (surveillanceDetection == null)
                    return false;
                else if (surveillanceDetection.Count > 0)
                    hasDetections = true;

                IList<ClsSurveillanceRobotStatus> surveillanceRobotStatus = GetRobotStatusData(dStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dEnd.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), kilometersDroven);
                if (surveillanceRobotStatus == null)
                    return false;

                //reset report
                rpt.Reset();
                rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                //set dataset
                var rDSTasks = new ReportDataSource { Value = surveillanceTasks, Name = "dsTasks" };
                rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rDSTasks);

                var rDSDetections = new ReportDataSource { Value = surveillanceDetection, Name = "dsDetections" };
                rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rDSDetections);

                var rDSRobotStatus = new ReportDataSource { Value = surveillanceRobotStatus, Name = "dsRobotStatus" };
                rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rDSRobotStatus);

                //Set report path
                rpt.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

                //Parameters
                var reportDate = dStart.Date;
                var monthName = new DateTime(reportDate.Date.Year, reportDate.Date.Month, reportDate.Date.Day).ToString("MMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var formatedDate = reportDate.Date.Day + " " + monthName + " " + reportDate.Date.Year;
                var rptParams = new ReportParameter[] { 
                new ReportParameter("nowDate", formatedDate),
                new ReportParameter("Company", company), 
                new ReportParameter("Adres", adres), 
                new ReportParameter("Postcode", postcode), 
                new ReportParameter("Place", place), 
                new ReportParameter("hasDetections", hasDetections.ToString()), 
                new ReportParameter("hasTaken", hasTaken.ToString())
                };

                rpt.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);

                try
                {
                    //Set page Settings to prevent big margins
                    var pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings
                    {
                        Margins = { Top = 16, Bottom = 16, Left = 16, Right = 16 }
                    };

                    rpt.SetPageSettings(pg);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHandler(ex);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHandler(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

GetTaskData is returning data and there is no nulls in it.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, this is to weird for me to understand.. So i fixed the issue, and i fixed it by removing the dataset and re-add it again to my report, so basically i deleted the dataset and added the same dataset and now it is working..

Answer (score 0):

This is an RDLC error itself. It is trying to parse your date, but it fails to do so. This is caused by a faulty date that you are trying to print in the report.
You can debug this by using several dates.

Start by printing     `formatedDate`     in a .NET message (or retrieve it with the .net debugger). Also remove any formatting from the date field in your report. Just dump the variable in the report. Faulty formatting is probably the problem.

Asides, debugging rdlc is annoying. If you are out of ideas, you should check out the xml-dataset to see in which way you are actually pushing data to your report.

Comment: Hey Fons Duin i've tried to remove the date from my report, making sure there was no weird date format but still does not work, i still get the #Error on my report.